# How do I set a backwards selection?

Tags: javascript, textarea, selection

I'm working on a custom tokenfield based on textarea. The idea is to have a textarea with div elements absolutely positioned above, so it *looks* like they are in text area.

It was pain so far, but I managed to do pretty much everything, except one thing.

Is it even possible in javascript to set reverse-selection? When you put a cursor somewhere in the middle of textarea, hold down shift and press left arrow a few times, you'll get a selection. The tricky part, is that it's not usual - it's backwards (it's start is to the right from the end, not like it is usually). There are placeholders in my textarea over which I display my divs (tokens). When you navigate to one of them, cursor jumps to the opposite edge of a placeholder, so it feels natural. When you hold down shift, and reach the placeholder, it jumps to the right, and it sets a new selection, so it looks like you selected the token (you can press delete, and remove selected range with token itself, which is cool). BUT it wont possibly work if you navigate from right to left, because setting a new selection would make it unreverted one:

**Left-to-right selection:**

```
abcde[start]efg[end](token)
[shift]+[right]
abcde[start]efg(token)[end]
[del]
abcde
```

**Right-to-left selection**

```
(token)[end]efg[start]abcde
[shift]+[left]
[start](token)abcdeefg[end] //see? it's back to normal
[shift]+[left]
[start](token)abcdeef[end]g //huh?! shift-right moves end point (unexpected)
abcde
```

So here's question: Can I set a selection in textarea where start point would be greater than the end point? Simply `element.setSelectionRange(right, left)` does not work in firefox, any other ideas?

Comment: This is VERY interesting, can I get a link or is it supersecret NASA stuff? :)

Comment: It's still work in progress widget. But i could probably release it (it's mootools) when i'm sure it's done.

Here is an image to give you an idea how it works: http://img.skitch.com/20091217-89kmqxu8subd5xr8yn1ut7953b.png (it sniffes for all kind of events and tries to render it in a hidden div, then calculates the positions of tokens and repositions things above textarea)


It's actually a clone of tokenfield in Mail.app in Mac OS X. Pretty darn close clone :)

Comment: Please do release it, it would be extremely interesting to study it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting a bit in the Firebug console, I think it is not trivial. However, you can intercept the keypress event:

If the user presses the left arrow, you have to extend the selection to the left yourself and return `false`. Then the browser's default is not called, but the user has nevertheless the feeling of a leftwards selection.

```
textarea.onkeypress = function (event) {
  if (!event){event = window.event; /* %#$! IE */ }
  if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 37 /* left */) {
    event.target.selectionStart = currentSelectionStart - 1;
  }
  return false;
};
```

37 is the left arrow, 38 is up, 39 is right and 40 is down.

Comment: Yes, but it's not trivial as well, because i'll have to listen to all the events that could probably disselect a piece of text or set a new selection.

But I somehow think it will be the only way (even if it's not easy to track selectionstart events x-browserly).

Thanks for trying though.